# How do I get the IPython version from inside IPython?

Tags: ipython

How do I get the IPython version I'm currently using?

I'm aware of `sys.version`, but that's the *Python* version I'm currently using.

And I'm aware of `ipython --version` (on the command-line), but I want to check *inside* the current IPython session. `!ipython --version` doesn't work for me cause I might have multiple IPython versions installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can `import IPython`, then use `IPython.version_info` to get it as a tuple, or `IPython.__version__` to get it as a string. For example:

```
In [1]: import IPython

In [2]: IPython.version_info
Out[2]: (4, 1, 2, '')

In [3]: IPython.__version__
Out[3]: '4.1.2'
```

`IPython.version_info` seems to be the same layout as `sys.version_info`: major, minor, micro, releaselevel.

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
ipython --version
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I want to get the version number from within the current IPython session.

Comment: Then do the exact same thing prefixed with a !

Comment: @David As I mentioned in the question, "`!ipython --version` doesn't work for me cause I might have multiple IPython versions installed"